# Не работает sql запрос insert into

Tags: php, mysql

```
$nameFile=1415;
    $nameGrup='A';   
      mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO `groupe`(`seson`, `name`) VALUES ('$nameFile','$nameGrup')");
```

в переменной conncet хранится подключение к sql.

Comment: В чём заключается ошибка?

Comment: Если проблема в том, что не вставляются нужные значения, то это из-за того что переменные находятся в одинарных кавычках

Comment: или можно писать их внутри { }